# Как интегрировать отправку почты на свой сайт?

Tags: email, интеграция

Ребят, всем привет. Как интегрировать отправку почты на свой сайт. Допустим посетителю нужно будет ввести только свою почту и само сообщение в поля и это сообщение само будет отправляться мне на почту? Может какие-то статьи вы знаете или что-то вроде этого, потому что лично я ничего толкового не нашел

Comment: Для начала уточните, на чем написан Ваш сайт? CMS, самописный? Находится на хостинге или VPS?

Comment: Самописный сайт, html, css, js. На VPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код из личных запасов:

```php
<?php
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
$message = trim($_POST['message']);

// указываем адрес отправителя, можно указать адрес на домене Вашего сайта
$fromMail = 'admin@domain.com';
$fromName = 'DOMAIN.COM Форма';

// Сюда введите Ваш email
$emailTo = 'youemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Форма обратной связи на php';
$subject = '=?utf-8?b?'. base64_encode($subject) .'?=';
$headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ". $fromName ." <". $fromMail ."> \r\n";

// тело письма
$body = "Получено письмо с сайта domain.com \n Имя: $name\nТелефон: $phone \n E-mail: $email\nСообщение: $message";

// сообщение будет отправлено в случае, если поле с номером телефона не пустое
if (strlen($phone) > 0) {
    $mail = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f'. $fromMail );
}
```

Поправьте под свои нужды и направьте на него форму, желательно по ajax. если без, то поставьте редирект в конце кода.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!)